# I am intermittent error Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking sometimes on page load not always.

Tags: content-delivery, content-manager

Server Error in '/' Application.

## Could not initialize class com.tridion.linking.Linking

Some configured classpath roots cannot be found

================================================

```
ClassPath           : F:\Websites\Tridion\intervetZAPROD\bin\bin
```

============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

============================================================

com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataRequestContext
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataFeedRenderer
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.ComponentPresentationEntity
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessToken
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.TemplatePropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.StructureGroupResolver
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.DynamicComponentLinkHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.PageEntity
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataLink
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.Association
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchResponse
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.TemplateEntity
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.CustomMetaEntity
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.TemplatesResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.DataService
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.FunctionImport
  com.tridion.linking.Linking
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.PublicationEntity
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataEntry
  com.tridion.util.ServiceExtensionLoader
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.JPQLExecutionException
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.RootServiceRenderer
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataBinaryContent
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.batching.parser.ODataConstants
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.PageContentResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.AssociationSet
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.BinaryPropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataProperty
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataContextListener
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataBaseType
  com.tridion.webservices.security.validator.OAuth2RequestValidator
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.KeywordEntity
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataMediaType
  com.tridion.linking.ASPLinking
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.syntax.SyntaxCheckerHelper
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.TemplateResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.KeywordPropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.KeywordResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataType
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2ResponseMessage
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.JPQLOrderByComposer
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.ParentResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataResponse
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.JPQLExecutor$OPERATOR
  com.tridion.util.HttpStatusCodes
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.elements.ComposerBase
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.DynamicComponentLinkingAdaptor
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.LinkingService
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.StructureGroupEntity
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.exceptions.ODataException
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.ChildrenResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataPublicationMappingFilter
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataFeed
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.PublicationsResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.BinaryLinkingAdaptor
  [Lcom.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.JPQLExecutor$OPERATOR;
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.ComponentLinkingAdaptor
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.SchemasResolver
  [Lcom.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.elements.filter.FilterValue$FilterValueType;
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.PagesResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.ODataInputParser
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.BinariesResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.SchemaEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.PublicationEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.AssociationSetEnd
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.batching.response.BatchResponse
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.IncrementKeyHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.ODataInputElement
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TargetGroupHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.EntityContainer
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.PageEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.exceptions.ODataUnsuportedHTTPMethodException
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataCategory
  [Lcom.tridion.webservices.odata.batching.parser.ODataConstants$HttpMethod;
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.exceptions.FeedBuildingException
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.batching.parser.BatchRequestBodyParser
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenProcessor
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.KeywordEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.SchemaEntity
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.BinaryResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.InvalidTokenException
  com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.StructureGroupEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.StructureGroupPropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataContent
  com.tridion.web.asp.ASPAdmin
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataUrlRewriter
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.CustomMetaPropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.JAXBContextResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.elements.filter.FilterFunctionCustom
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.batching.parser.BatchRequestEntry
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataErrorResponse
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.root.ODataService$ServiceCollection
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.Entity
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.KeywordsResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.ComponentEntity
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.BinaryVariantsResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.PageContentsResolver
  com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.ODataMetaDataService
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.elements.orderby.OrderByDirection
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.CustomMetaEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.CustomMetasResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchResponseBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.ComponentPresentationPropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataInlineFeed
  [Lcom.tridion.util.HttpStatusCodes;
  [Lcom.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataEntryRelationModificationType;
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.BinaryMetaEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.PageContentEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.ODataInputElementType
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataEntryRelationModificationType
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.exceptions.ODataParsingException
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.BinaryVariantEntity
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.elements.orderby.OrderByOperator
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.FunctionImport$Parameter
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.elements.filter.FilterValue$FilterValueType
  com.tridion.util.ServiceExtensionException
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.elements.filter.FilterKeyword
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.PageResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.TemplateEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.ComponentPresentationsResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.Key
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.batching.parser.ParsingUtility
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.PropertyRenderer
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.ComponentResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.PageContentEntity
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.AssociationEnd
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.MetadataSchema
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.NavigationProperty
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.exceptions.ODataStorageException
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.root.ODataService$ServiceWorkspace
  [Lcom.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataBaseType;
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.exceptions.ODataValidationException
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionsHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.elements.filter.FilterValue
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.PublicationPropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataAuthor
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.batching.response.ChangeSetResponse
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.PageContentPropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.ComponentsResolver
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.PagePropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.webservices.linking.adaptors.PageLinkingAdaptor
  [Lcom.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataType;
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.ComponentPropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.BinaryLinkHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.batching.parser.Batch
  com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentLinkHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.ComponentPresentationEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.ComponentEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TaxonomyHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.BinaryVariantEntryBuilder
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.BinaryVariantPropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.PropertyRef
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.validation.ValidationFacade
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.batching.parser.ODataConstants$HttpMethod
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.exceptions.ODataIdentifierException
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.entities.BinaryEntity
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.PageLinkHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataEntityRelationElement
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.elements.ElementParser
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataErrorResponse$ODataErrorResponseMessage
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.EntryExpander
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.batching.parser.ODataBatchRelationElement
  com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.JPQLExecutor
  com.tridion.web.Admin
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataJsonTransformer
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataWebservice
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.EntitySet
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.StructureGroupsResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.root.ODataService
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.batching.parser.ChangeSet
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentPresentationHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.metadata.schema.Property
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.SchemaResolver
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.SchemaPropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.ResolverBase
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataEntryRegistrationService
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataServiceOperation
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataWritableEntryService
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.jpql.elements.ElementBase
  com.tridion.webservices.extension.ODataWritableStreamEntryService
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.validation.EntityParser
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.ODataBase
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.PropertyWrapper
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.builders.EntryBuilder
  com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.LinkBaseHandler
  com.tridion.webservices.odata.model.wrappers.ItemMetaPropertyWrapper

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for. Please clarify the question